# Design Views for a Mac App

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, app-store

Is there any way to create an app for the Mac App Store in much the same way as you do for the iPhone/iPad app store?  Using Interface Builder or some similar program for creating views that will connect to the code with IBOutlets and IBActions?

If not, can anybody outline what is needed to create Mac Apps as opposed to iOS apps and perhaps point to a good tutorial, sample source code, or documentation resource?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

The technology is much the same for both Mac OS and iOS. You use Xcode and Interface Builder. iOS uses CocoaTouch whereas Mac OS X uses Cocoa (from which CocoaTouch was derived).

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same, but instead of UIViewControllers you use NSViewControllers. NSView is slightly different from UIView but the subview-mechanism is identical.

Comment: You certainly can use NSViewControllers, but using them isn't as widespread on the Mac, partly because it's a relatively new class (introduced in Leopard), partly because it's nowhere near as featureful as its Cocoa Touch cousin.

Comment: Well, I'm using it all the time. It's the great C of MVC.